# Integration of Arbitrary Java Machine Learning with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, concurrency

Basically what I need to do is to integrate the [CTBNCToolkit](https://github.com/dcodecasa/CTBNCToolkit) with Apache Spark, so this toolkit can take advantage of the concurrency and clustering features of Apache Spark.

In general I want to know is there any way exposed by **[Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/)** developers to integrate any Java/Scala library in a fashion that the machine learning library can run on top of **Spark's concurrency management**?

**So the goal is to make the stand alone machine learning libraries faster and concurrent.**

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

So what you want is that any algorithm runs on Spark. But, to parallelize the work, Spark uses `RDD`s or `Dataset`s. So in order to run your tasks in parallel, the algorithms would have to use these classes.

The only thing that you could try, is to write your own Spark program, that makes use of any other library. But I'm not sure whether that's possible in your case. However, isn't Spark ML enough for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "However, isn't Spark ML enough for you?" Actually I can't see Spark ML offering any CTBNC algorithms.  Continuous Time Bayesian Network Classifiers